# MySQL pivot table for attendance per weekdays of week

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, mysql-workbench

For a date interval, I want to display the attendance per weekdays of students records, recorded in three tables [Attendance, Students, Person]. The schema (relevant fields) of tables:

```
Attendance Table
--------------------- 
Attendance_Identifier 
Student_Identifier 
Classroom_Identifier 
Attendance_Datetime 
Attendance_Value 
...


Student
------------------
Student_Identifier
Person_Identifier
Classroom_Identifier
...

Person
-----------------
Person_Identifier
Frist_Name
Last_Name
Gender
...
```

**Expected Report Output:**

> ```
> Gender    Student     Mon     Tue     Wed     Thu     Fri     WeeklyTotal
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Male     Ab Stain     2/10    3/12    1/9     1/10    0/10    7/51
> Male     Pre Senter   10/10   12/12   9/9     9/10    10/10   50/51
> ...
> Female    Al Ways     10/10   12/12   9/9     10/10   10/10   51/51
> Female    Not Often   5/10    5/12    4/9     4/10    5/10    23/51
> ...
> ```

I also have a function to get the count of particular day of week from a date interval say for total Mondays in date interval @s, @e, just do: `select get_weekday(@s,@e,0).`

So my query for my stored procedure is :

```
set @s = '2016-01-01';
set @e = '2016-12-07';
SELECT 
concat(p.Frist_Name, ' ',p.Last_Name) as Student, p.Gender
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a') = 'Mon' 
        THEN CONCAT(COUNT(Attendance_Value),'/',get_weekday(@s,@e,0)) ELSE NULL END) AS Mon
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a') = 'Tue' 
        THEN CONCAT(COUNT(Attendance_Value),'/',get_weekday(@s,@e,1)) ELSE NULL END) AS Tue
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a') = 'Wed' 
        THEN CONCAT(COUNT(Attendance_Value),'/',get_weekday(@s,@e,2)) ELSE NULL END) AS Wed
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a') = 'Thu' 
        THEN CONCAT(COUNT(Attendance_Value),'/',get_weekday(@s,@e,3)) ELSE NULL END) AS Thu
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a') = 'Fri' 
        THEN CONCAT(COUNT(Attendance_Value),'/',get_weekday(@s,@e,4)) ELSE NULL END) AS Fri
    , SUM(COUNT(Attendance_Value)) as WeeklyTotal
FROM Attendance a JOIN Student s ON s.Student_Identifier=a.Student_Identifier 
JOIN Person p ON p.Person_Identifier=s.Person_Identifier 
WHERE date(Attendance_Datetime) BETWEEN @s AND @e AND a.Classroom_Identifier = '363'
AND (Attendance_Value = 'Present' OR Attendance_Value = 'Late') AND (p.Gender = 'Male' OR p.Gender = 'Female') 
AND DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a') !='Sat' AND DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a')!='Sun' 
GROUP BY p.Gender, Student, WeeklyTotal ORDER BY p.Gender, Student;
```

And I get the following group function error each time even with many tweaks to the code.

```
Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function
```

### Edit

Based on @Solarflare 's first suggestion (I don't know how to try the second one), I got the query refined to:

```
SELECT 
concat(p.Frist_Name, ' ',p.Last_Name) as Student, p.Gender
    ,CONCAT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a') = 'Mon' 
        THEN COUNT(Attendance_Value) ELSE 0 END,'/',get_weekday(@s,@e,0) ) AS Mon
    ,CONCAT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a') = 'Tue' 
        THEN COUNT(Attendance_Value) ELSE 0 END,'/',get_weekday(@s,@e,1) ) AS Tue
    ,CONCAT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a') = 'Wed' 
        THEN COUNT(Attendance_Value) ELSE 0 END,'/',get_weekday(@s,@e,2) ) AS Wed
    ,CONCAT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a') = 'Thu' 
        THEN COUNT(Attendance_Value) ELSE 0 END,'/',get_weekday(@s,@e,3) ) AS Thu
    ,CONCAT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a') = 'Fri' 
        THEN COUNT(Attendance_Value) ELSE 0 END,'/',get_weekday(@s,@e,4) ) AS Fri
    , COUNT(Attendance_Value) as WeeklyTotal
FROM Attendance a JOIN Student s ON s.Student_Identifier=a.Student_Identifier 
JOIN Person p ON p.Person_Identifier=s.Person_Identifier 
WHERE date(Attendance_Datetime) BETWEEN @s AND @e AND a.Classroom_Identifier = '363'
AND (Attendance_Value = 'Present' OR Attendance_Value = 'Late') AND (p.Gender = 'Male' OR p.Gender = 'Female') 
AND DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a') !='Sat' AND DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a')!='Sun' 
GROUP BY Student,Gender,DATE_FORMAT(Attendance_Datetime, '%a') ORDER BY p.Gender, Student,Mon DESC;
```

and the result is as below:

[image]

Comment: You cannot use `group_concat(count())`, which would be a double group. I don't think you need a group_concat there at all; you can probably put the case inside the `count()`, something like `concat(count(case when ... = 'Wed' ... else null end), ' /', ...)` and so on. If not, make a subquery for the pivot first, then the formatting stuff.

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare for your suggestions, the first one helped get output to almost as expected, please see main Question EDIT, to see if you help further :)

Comment: You are grouping by the weekday. So you get one row for each day. You don't want that. Place the whole `case...end` INSIDE the counts. If you provide the table creates and sample data (e.g. as an sql fiddle), I can test it, but I think the code I posted in my first comment should work.

Comment: Hi @Solarflare, your advise helped, but still not as expected. Please take a look at the sql fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd93f/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were just some minor things left to make it work, try this:

```
SELECT 
  concat(p.Frist_Name, ' ',p.Last_Name) as Student, p.Gender
  ,concat(cast(COUNT(CASE WHEN weekday(Attendance_Datetime) = 0
     then 1 END) as char), '/', get_weekday(@s,@e,0)) as Mon
  ,concat(cast(COUNT(CASE WHEN weekday(Attendance_Datetime) = 1
     then 1 END) as char), '/', get_weekday(@s,@e,1)) as Tue
  ,concat(cast(COUNT(CASE WHEN weekday(Attendance_Datetime) = 2
     then 1 END) as char), '/', get_weekday(@s,@e,2)) as Wed
  ,concat(cast(COUNT(CASE WHEN weekday(Attendance_Datetime) = 3
     then 1 END) as char), '/', get_weekday(@s,@e,3)) as Thu
  ,concat(cast(COUNT(CASE WHEN weekday(Attendance_Datetime) = 4
     then 1 END) as char), '/', get_weekday(@s,@e,4)) as Fri
  ,COUNT(Attendance_Value) as WeeklyTotal
FROM Attendance a 
JOIN Student s ON s.Student_Identifier=a.Student_Identifier 
JOIN Person p ON p.Person_Identifier=s.Person_Identifier 
WHERE date(Attendance_Datetime) BETWEEN @s AND @e 
  AND a.Classroom_Identifier = '363'
  AND (Attendance_Value = 'Present' OR Attendance_Value = 'Late') 
  AND (p.Gender = 'Male' OR p.Gender = 'Female') 
  AND weekday(Attendance_Datetime) not in (5,6)
GROUP BY Student, Gender ORDER BY p.Gender, Student, Mon DESC;
```

The pivot is done with the `case`, it counts when the date has the correct weekday. Otherwise the value is `null` (not `0`), only then it doesn't count (`else null` has not to be written).